# Python performance. Search for items with errors in the list

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary

I'm analyzing sequencing data. At one stage I have a dictionary *{bcCountSorted}* with nucleotide sequences (barcodes) and a list *[bcSortedList]* of these barcodes, sorted by the frequency of occurrence.
So they look like:

```
>>> head(bcCountSorted)
('CTAGACGGTGCCGAAGTC', 8)
('CTGGGTCCCCACCATCCC', 8)
('TACAGTGGACTAGGCGAA', 7)
('ATCTACGAGTCGTCCAAC', 7)
('AGTCTGCGGAAATGCCAA', 7)

>>> head(bcSortedList)
CCCGACATTCGAGCACGT
ACGACTTGTGATAAAACG
CAGCCTACAGTTCTCCCC
AAGTTGCCCGGACAGTTT
ACACCCACTTCCAGGATC
```

Next, I need to find all mutant barcode variants from the *bcCountSorted* dictionary in the *bcSortedList* list, and then remove the found mutant variants from the *bcSortedList*

The following code performs this task:

```
import regex

for item in bcCountSorted:
    expr = regex.compile("({})".format(item[0]) + "{e<=" + str (barcodeError) + "}")
    tmpListBc = [bcSortedList.pop(bcSortedList.index(l)) for l in bcSortedList for m in [expr.search(l)] if m]
    if len(tmpListBc)> 0:
        tmpElementDict = [(x, bcCountSortedDict[x]) for x in tmpListBc]
        bcDict [tmpListBc[0]] = tmpElementDict
```

Where:

**expr** is a regular expression with an allowable error level of 2 (*barcodeError*), executed for ~ 5*10^-6 seconds

**item[0]** is the nucleotide sequence, for example *'CTAGACGGTGCCGAAGTC'*

**tmpListBc** is the list comprehension, find the sequence, which are immediately removed from the *bcSortedList* list. In progress for 55 seconds.

Hence the problem. The number of elements in the dictionary *bcCountSorted* = 10,000,000, the items in the list *bcSortedList* ~ 7,500,000. Since one loop is executed in one processor mode for ~55 seconds, in order for the task to be performed in an acceptable time, it is necessary that one loop is executed no longer than 0.004 seconds.

Comment: The code provided contains several errors and omissions does not run.  The code could be made faster but it is clear the problem here is not the implementation as mush as the algorithm choice.  I'd recommend looking into smarter algorithms for doing this rather than trying to improve this code.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.coursera.org/learn/dna-sequencing/lecture/JAVzv/lecture-approximate-matching-hamming-and-edit-distance) course

Comment: Could you please give a justification for needing this to run in 4ms? That's a very aggressive goal and, while I think the algorithm can be improved, I don't think you can do any reasonable amount of work on 17 million elements in 4ms.

Comment: I probably did not say so. I need 4ms for loop, the overall code execution time in this case is about 11 hours.

Comment: @FujiApple, this code is only a small part of a larger script. Therefore, without the appropriate environment, it will not work. As for another algorithm, I already had the idea that a simple search of combinations is very inefficient. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Building a FST on `bcSortedList` in order to find entries within a given levenshtein-distance is probably the way to go here. See [here](http://blog.burntsushi.net/transducers/) for an example.

Comment: Only Levenshtein's distance algorithm is suitable for my problem, since two strings can have different lengths in my case. The fastest implementation ([page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.12.0)) of this algorithm is performed for 3.21 ms for loop ([benchmark](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/editdistance))

Comment: @user2722968, I did not see your answer first. Thanks, I'll try also to use this implementation of the Levenshtein algorithm